# Extract IP and a word from string using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

How to extract word `Connected` and `14.10.9.24` from the following string using Python regular expression.

Input:

```
Connected,abc,hhjj,kkll,14.10.9.24,out
```

Comment: This is the output of a command. I just want to extract the word and ip from it. Can anyone help?

Comment: what makes "Connected" a word and "hhjj" not a word?

Comment: Actually I need "Connected" and ip from it

Comment: Do you really need "Connected"? What else can it be? If you don't want the line if "Connected" isn't there, just test for it and move on. E.g. `line.startswith("Connected,")`

Comment: m=re.search('Connected.+[0-9.]+',output_string).

Comment: I tried with this but it prints everything after Connected

Answer (score 1):

Split by comma and take the first and fifth elements of the array, assuming the format of the output is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the job:

```
^(connected)(,\w+)+,([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})(,\w+)$/im
```

Required fields are in group 1 and 3.

[Demo](http://regexr.com?31ko8)

Answer (score 0):

An example using `str.split` and `operator.itemgetter`...:

```
from operator import itemgetter

line = 'Connected,abc,hhjj,kkll,14.10.9.24,out'

word, ip = itemgetter(0, 4)(line.split(','))
```